# BuddyPress: Allow only one email domain to register

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

In the BuddyPress, I want to allow register and log in using only one email domain. For instance, xxx@myemaildomain.com restore all will be disallowed.

I have checked in the BuddyPress source and found that BuddyPress is using `bp_core_validate_user_signup( $user_name, $user_email )` for sign up that has a filter

```
return apply_filters( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', $result );
```

So I have tried to use the filter to modify the `user_email` filed as in the code below. But it is not working.

```
function wf_validate_email_domain($result)
{

    $email = $result[ 'user_email' ];

    // make sure we've got a valid email
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // split on @ and return last value of array (the domain)
        $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

        if ($domain != 'mydomain.com') {
            $result[ 'user_email' ] = '';
        }
    }

    return $result;

}

add_filter('bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'wf_validate_email_domain', 9999);
```

> **Question:**
>
> How can I validate email so it allows to register and login only from
>   one specific email domain?

Comment: So given a string with an email in it, how do you test if the email belongs to a particular domain? Or do you know that part but are asking how to use the `bp_core_validate_user_signup` filter?

Comment: @TomJNowell well, I don't know if I am using this filter in wrong way. However, I found sign up the action and that solved my problem. I will post the answer later today.

Comment: The WordPress core way would be to return a WP_Error if the email domain didn't match, not just clear the address, but I don't know if BuddyPress would cope with that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Here is the code if anyone has the same issue and want to refer it.

## Using Action

```
function wf_validate_email_domain()
{
    global $bp;

    $email          = $bp->signup->email;
    $email_exploded = explode('@', $email);
    // split on @ and return last value of array (the domain)
    $domain = array_pop($email_exploded);

    $email_domains = get_option('allowed_email_domains');

    $allowed_email_domains = array_map('trim', explode(',', $email_domains));

    if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed_email_domains)) {
        $bp->signup->errors[ 'signup_email' ] = __('You cannot register using this email', 'workfront');
    }

}

add_action('bp_signup_validate', 'wf_validate_email_domain');
```

I also found a solution using the same filter as in my question. The answer provided by [@Damocles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10122947/damocles) and here is the [original answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078521/1053190). However, for convenience, I am pasting code here.

## Using Filter

```
function wf_validate_email_domain($result)
{

    $email = $result[ 'user_email' ];

    // make sure we've got a valid email
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // split on @ and return last value of array (the domain)
        $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

        $email_domains = get_option('allowed_email_domains');

        $allowed_email_domains = array_map('trim', explode(',', $email_domains));

        if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed_email_domains)) {
            $result[ 'errors' ]->add('user_email', __('You cannot register using this email', 'workfront'));
        }

    }

    return $result;

}

add_filter('bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'wf_validate_email_domain');
```

Comment: If this works you should accept your own answer so future users know immediately that there's a working solution.  :-)